# Calling a method using NSTimer in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer, userinfo

I want to call a method(with one parameter) using NSTimer but still keep on getting errors. This is how my method looks like:

```
    func addEnemy(scnView: SCNView) {
        func createMeteorite() -> SCNNode {
            let meteorite = Meteorite(scnView: scnView, speed: calculateSpeed())
            return meteorite
        }
    self.rootNode.addChildNode(createMeteorite())
}
```

And my instance of NSTimer:

```
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("addEnemy:"), userInfo: scnView, repeats: true)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In which line you are getting error?

Comment: The timer function must take a NSTimer argument: `func addEnemy(timer :  NSTimer)`, as explained in the answer to the duplicate question.